# Is it correct to say: It's not ripened yet

Tags: grammar

I'd like to ask you all that is it correct grammatically to say: It's not ripened yet, and I'm not done yet ? Are they equivalent to saying It hasn't ripened yet and I haven't done yet ?

I'm asking because the usual expression for the use of *ripe* in this context is *It's not ripe yet* or "It hasn't ripened yet".

[Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=not+ripe+yet%2Cnot+ripened+yet&year_start=1960&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnot%20ripe%20yet%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnot%20ripened%20yet%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

Thanks very much.

Comment: “I haven't done yet” is not a complete sentence. What haven't you done yet? And what do you intend your sentences to actually mean? Some context is necessary.

Comment: The two standard forms in U.S. English for describing something as not yet ripe (besides "It's still green") are "It hasn't ripened yet" and "It isn't ripe yet." The wording you suggest splits the difference between those two wordings, and in doing so falls between two stools.

Answer (score 1):

I like this question - stimulating. I believe the forms of the statements are equivalent. "It is not ripened yet" seems at first sight to confuse present and past but I understand it as shorthand for "It is not (at the stage where it has) ripened yet." The parenthetical text would put the tenses into order but adds nothing, so why bother with it? Similarly with "I am not (at the the stage where I am) done yet."

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Expressions such as It's not ripened yet and I'm not done yet are only used in spoken language and informal writing, right? in formal writing such as in academic texts, they must be written in the full form, right ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It's can either be *it is* or *it has*.
[It's](http://speakspeak.com/grammar-articles/its-is-has-difference) becomes *it has* when it is followed by a past participle. Since ripened is the past participle of ripen, it's becomes *'It has not ripened yet'*.

Comment: ''It's not ripened yet'' here I mean it is not ripened yet. Is it the same as it has not ripened yet ?

Comment: It's not the same. *It has* is correct because ripened is in past tense. However, when you use *it's* followed by a word in past tense, *it's* automatically becomes *it has*.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest *It's not ripe yet* . 
*It hasn't ripened yet* is similar the sounds like it is in the past tense